# Correct syntax to convert my jQuery script to a reusable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So I have a script structured like this:

```
$('.save-audition').on('click', function() {
    STUFF HAPPENS HERE
})
```

It's working great. But, there are several elements besides .save-audition that I would like to use the same script with just a few variables different. By searching around, I thought the below would work, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. What's the correct syntax I should be using?

```
$('.save-audition').on('click', tps_save_listing(audition));
$('.save-job').on('click', tps_save_listing(job));

function tps_save_listing(type) {
    STUFF HAPPENS HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling function immediately at `tps_save_listing(audition)`, `tps_save_listing(job)`, instead of passing reference to `tps_save_listing` function. You can alternatively use [`event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data) to pass variables to event handler `tps_save_listing`

```
$(".save-audition").on("click", null, audition, tps_save_listing);
$(".save-job").on("click", null, job, tps_save_listing);

function tps_save_listing(event) {
    // STUFF HAPPENS HERE
    console.log(event.data);
}
```

```js
var audition = 123;
var job = "abc";
$(".save-audition").on("click", null, audition, tps_save_listing);
$(".save-job").on("click", null, job, tps_save_listing);

function tps_save_listing(event) {
  console.log(event.data)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="save-audition">
save audition
</div>

<div class="save-job">
save job
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p1gcxw5y/

Comment: Thank you. All good answers but you were first and your solution worked for my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to design the function like a event handler only, then you can pass the value as the data like

```js
$('.save-audition').on('click', {
  type: 'audition'
}, tps_save_listing);
$('.save-job').on('click', {
  type: 'job'
}, tps_save_listing);

function tps_save_listing(event) {
  snippet.log(event.data.type)
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="save-audition">1</div>
<div class="save-audition">2</div>
<div class="save-job">3</div>
<div class="save-job">4</div>
```

---

The problem with your code is you are invoking the function immediately.

You can also use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```js
$('.save-audition').on('click', tps_save_listing.bind(window, 'audition'));
$('.save-job').on('click', tps_save_listing.bind(window, 'job'));

function tps_save_listing(type) {
  snippet.log(type)
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="save-audition">1</div>
<div class="save-audition">2</div>
<div class="save-job">3</div>
<div class="save-job">4</div>
```

Comment: Snippet logged `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('[object Window]') is not a valid name`.

Comment: @guest271314 which is the browser used? looks like it is from the `snippet.log()` statement

Comment: chromium.  Actually, second parameter passed to `.on()` is expected to be selector or `null`, see post, below, http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data. If you pass `null` as second parameter to `.on()`, then event data the error is not logged. Why set `this` to `window` instead of original selector at `.bind()`?

Comment: @guest271314 `this` is suppose to be the dom element reference, not a jQuery object so setting the selector may not solve that issue

Comment: @guest271314 the format used above is http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler where both `selector` and `data` are optional

Comment: You are correct, returns correct results at jsfiddle, where `selector` is omitted. Would `this` be `window` if `context` is set to `window` at `.bind()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114173/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is called function application. Try out the code below, then I can explain what is going on.

```js
$('.button1').on('click', applied(myFunction, ['foo']));
$('.button2').on('click', applied(myFunction, ['bar', ' bat']));

function myFunction(text1, text2) {
  alert(text1);

  if (text2)
    alert(text2)
}

function applied(func, args) {
  return function() {
    func.apply(null, args);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button1">Foo</button>
<button class="button2">Bar</button>
```

What is happening here is that when we call `applied(myFunction, ['foo'])`, we are actually creating a brand new, anonymous function with pre-specified parameters. This new, anonymous function is returned, and in turn will be call our original function with the parameters we have specified when the 'click' event is fired.

For convenience in this case, I've wrapped that functionality in a function called 'applied'.

More resources on this.

[Currying and Partial Functions](http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/currying-and-partial-functions-in-javasc/231001821)

[MDN on Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)